# How to condense data better using sql?

Tags: sql, presto

Let's say I have a table such as

| id | start_time | end_time | SomeField |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-06-09 10:59:55.000 | 2022-06-09 11:59:51.000 | A |
| 2 | 2022-06-09 10:59:56.000 | 2022-06-09 11:11:10.000 | A |
| 3 | 2022-06-09 11:19:20.000 | 2022-06-09 11:38:25.000 | A |
| 4 | 2022-06-09 11:19:20.000 | 2022-06-09 11:20:20.000 | B |
| 5 | 2022-06-09 11:22:20.000 | 2022-06-09 11:24:20.000 | B |

In which I need to generated a condensed version of this with overlapping start and end times, such as:

| Start_time | End_time | SomeField |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-09 10:59:56.000 | 2022-06-09 11:59:51.000 | A |
| 2022-06-09 11:19:20.000 | 2022-06-09 11:20:20.000 | B |
| 2022-06-09 11:22:20.000 | 2022-06-09 11:24:20.000 | B |

In this case, I can't just do a max(),min() of start and end times since there is an overlap of id's 1-3, in which I need the first row to essentially represent the total time span of SomeField A and I also need the 2 records of SomeField B since there is a gap in time spans

Comment: in your expected result is `start_time` = `2022-06-09 10:59:56.000` an error? did you mean `2022-06-09 10:59:55.000`

Comment: @Jacky no, that is intended

Comment: I think you might want to select MAX Start_Time and End_Time with group by SomeFiel

Comment: I think I addressed the issue in the post. I need those 2 records where SomeField = B since there is a gap between the time spans of the 2 id's @L.Newell

Comment: @user7298979 For SomeField = B, do you mean a gap between the End_Time of ID 4 and the Start_Time of ID 5? Just trying to wrap my head around the logic for selecting 10:59:56.000 for SomeField A as well - what is the reason/logic around that time needing to be selected?

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @Jacky there's no possible logic where the output makes sense as `2022-06-09 10:59:56.000` over `2022-06-09 10:59:55.000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting method I developed for Trino that should work the same for Presto. It utilizes geometric functions to bypass many of the traditional methods to solve the overlapping time-period simplification problem.

```
WITH condensed as (
    SELECT SomeField,
    transform(                                               -- 6) See Below~
      ST_Geometries(                                         -- 5) Extracts an array of individual lines from the union.
        geometry_union(                                      -- 4) Returns the union of aggregated lines, melding all lines together into a single geometric multi-line.
          array_agg(                                         -- 3) Aggregation function that joins all lines based on account/ticket id together.
            ST_LineString(                                   -- 2) Makes the pairs of geometric points into lines.
                ARRAY[ST_Point(0, to_unixtime(start_time)),
                      ST_Point(0, to_unixtime(end_time))]    -- 1) Takes unix time start and end values and makes them into an array of geometric points.
            )
          )
        )
      )
    , x -> (ST_YMin(x), ST_YMax(x))) AS new_start_end        -- 6) From the array of lines, The minimum and maximum value of each line is calculated. These are unix timestamps.
    FROM table
    GROUP BY SomeField
)
SELECT from_unixtime(start) start_time
     , from_unixtime(end) end_time
     , SomeField
FROM condensed
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(new_start_end) AS t(start, end)
```

---

Fully working example:

```
WITH the_table AS (
    SELECT id, CAST(start_time AS TIMESTAMP) start_time, CAST(end_time AS TIMESTAMP) end_time, SomeField
    FROM (VALUES ('1', '2022-06-09 10:59:55.000', '2022-06-09 11:59:51.000', 'A'),
                 ('2', '2022-06-09 10:59:56.000', '2022-06-09 11:11:10.000', 'A'),
                 ('3', '2022-06-09 11:19:20.000', '2022-06-09 11:38:25.000', 'A'),
                 ('4', '2022-06-09 11:19:20.000', '2022-06-09 11:20:20.000', 'B'),
                 ('5', '2022-06-09 11:22:20.000', '2022-06-09 11:24:20.000', 'B'))
            AS data(id, start_time, end_time, SomeField)
),
     condensed as (
    SELECT SomeField,
           transform(
               ST_Geometries(
                   geometry_union(
                       array_agg(
                           ST_LineString(
                               ARRAY[ST_Point(0, to_unixtime(start_time)),
                                     ST_Point(0, to_unixtime(end_time))]
                           )
                       )
                   )
               )
           , x -> (ST_YMin(x), ST_YMax(x))) AS new_start_end
    FROM the_table
    GROUP BY SomeField
)
SELECT CAST(from_unixtime(s) AS TIMESTAMP) start_time
     , CAST(from_unixtime(e) AS TIMESTAMP) end_time
     , SomeField
FROM condensed
         CROSS JOIN UNNEST(new_start_end) AS t(s, e)
```

Output:

| start_time | end_time | SomeField |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-09 10:59:55 | 2022-06-09 11:59:51 | A |
| 2022-06-09 11:19:20 | 2022-06-09 11:20:20 | B |
| 2022-06-09 11:22:20 | 2022-06-09 11:24:20 | B |